# Error en Conexión con MySQL - Entity Framework con MySQL

Tags: c#

amigos, necesito trabajar con Entity Framework con base de datos de MySQL, no he podido lograr configurar o recuperar los datos para el modelo en Visual Studio 2017.

Antes de escribir estuve investigando y encontré este link del foro en ingles, hice lo que mencionan pero siempre me envía error, me pueden ayudar a revisar que me hace falta.

este es el mensaje que tengo y es el mismo del link, seguí los pasos y nada

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206184/cant-use-a-mysql-connection-for-entity-framework-6

Comment: Hola alfredo, has intentado la solucion "actualizada" de 2017 del link que nos has pasado?

Comment: dices que "envia error", pero que dice ese error? que pasos has realizados de todos los que se mencionan en el link que proporcionas, porque dices que "sigues los pasos" pero alli hay muchas respuestas, cual de todos?

Comment: Buenas amigo, Capt. Teach, si segui los pasos, primero hice otro proyecto nuevo, instale desde el nuget el MySQL Data, luego el MySQL.Entity, en estos las ultimas versiones, luego, instale el Entity framework la version 6.0.1, segun me indica un ejemplo, luego, copie una parte de la cadena de conexion e inabilite la que me crea el VS por default.

Una vez que hice esto, me conecte, recupere las tablas, perfecto ALEGRE YO, pero cuando le doy modificar me envia nuevamente un mensaje de que no son compatibles, hasta alli llegue.

Comment: Saludos, leandro, segui los pasos e instale estos del nugget:
MySQL.Data
 6.9.12
EntityFramework (>= 6.0.0)
MySql.Data (>= 6.9.12)

MySql.Data.Entity
 6.9.12
Entity Framework
 6.0.1
luego modifique en el App.config:
Sustituyo esta cadena
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>, entonces se cierra o se queda pegad

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacer uso del proveedor de `Mysql`

[Entity Framework 6 Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Uno de los pasos importantes es agregar la referencia usando `nuget`

[MySql.Data.Entity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/)

Después defines el `dbcontext` y la class de la entidad que quieres "mapear":

```
public class NombreContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<NombreEntity> NombreEntities { get; set; }

    public NombreContext()
    : base()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class NombreEntity
{
    public int PropId { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Leandro, gracias por tu apoyo, este es el otro link que sigo, que habla de actualizar a VS2017;
https://entityframework.net/es/knowledge-base/22031269/habilitar-entity-framework-6-para-mysql--c-sharp--en-winforms-de-microsoft-visual-studio-2013

Comment: donde habla de actualizar VS2017 ?

Comment: En ninguna parte leandro, lo que me dice es seguir las instrucciones para visual studio eso quise decir. saludos